# Django cache invalidation on transaction commit?

Tags: django, caching, transactions, memcached, cache-invalidation

When developing your project in Django with READ-COMITTED level, I think cache.delete can lead to race condition and django's signals won't help much.

```
T1                          T2
                            cache.delete
cache.get (not found)
read from database
cache.set (old value again)
                            commit
                            cache.get (old value)
```

How can I ensure that cache invalidation is only done at the moment of transaction commit?

Answer (score 1):

You should only delete from cache when the transaction has been committed. To ensure your transaction has been committed (for example, in case you're using `django.middleware.transaction.TransactionMiddleware` to commit upon every request), you can force a commit using `commit_on_success`:

```
from django.db import transaction
with transaction.commit_on_success():
    # ... do db stuff ...

cache.delete('key')
```

Comment: Well, that sounds like commit-continue, which wouldn't let me to rollback in future part of the runtime. It seems, I either need something like version control or cache management middleware.

Comment: It would appear you need to define what to do with the cached value in case you do a rollback.